# wheel of emotions with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you please show me How can I draw the wheel of emotions pluchik ?
Like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your efforts so far so people don't have to start entirely from scratch? Or hire somebody if you want somebody to do the job for you, rather than help you solve some specific problem you're having.

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Answer (score 25):

I realise it is generally frowned upon to provide answers when the OP has not really done anything, but anyway this is a start...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.375cm,y=1.375cm]
\foreach \r in {4,3}
  \draw [dashed] circle [radius=\r];

\foreach \c [count=\i from 0] in  
  {green!50!black, green!75!brown, yellow!50!white, orange, red, magenta, blue, blue!50!cyan}{
  \foreach \s [count=\j from 0] in {25,50,75,100}{
    \begin{scope}[rotate=\i*45]
      \clip (0,0) -- (22.5:2)
        arc (90:0:3 and 2*sin 22.5)
        arc (360:270:3 and 2*sin 22.5) -- cycle;
      \fill [fill=\c!\s!white] circle [radius=5-\j];
      \draw circle [radius=5-\j];
     \end{scope}
}}

\foreach \i in {0,...,7}
  \draw [rotate=\i*45] (0,0) -- (22.5:2)  
    arc (90:0:3 and 2*sin 22.5)
    arc (360:270:3 and 2*sin 22.5);

\foreach \emotionlist [count=\i] in
  {{terruer,peur,apprehension},
   {admiration,confiance,acceptation},
   {extase,joie,s\'er\'enit\'e},
   {vigilance,anticipation,in\'er\^et},
   {rage,col\`ere,agacement},
   {r\'epugnance,d\'ego\^ut,ennui},
   {chagrin,tristesse,rumination},
   {stup\'efaction,surprise,distraction}}
  \foreach \emotion [count=\j] in \emotionlist
    \node [anchor=base, font=\footnotesize, emotion label \i-\j/.try] at (\i*45-45:\j+.5) {\emotion};

\foreach \emotion [count=\i] in
{soumission, amour, optimisme, agressivit\`e,m\'epris,remords,d\`esapprobation,respect}
  \node [anchor=base, font=\footnotesize]
    at (\i*45-22.5:4.75) {\emotion};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, I think this looks better:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.375cm,y=1.375cm]

\fill [even odd rule, gray!20] circle [radius=5] circle [radius=4] circle [radius=3];
\begin{scope}
\clip  (22.5:2) \foreach \i in {0,...,7}{ [rotate=-\i*45]
   arc (90:0:3 and 2*sin 22.5)  arc (360:270:3 and 2*sin 22.5)
 } -- cycle;

\foreach \c [count=\i from 0] in  
  {green!50!black, green!75!brown, yellow!50!white, orange, red, magenta, blue, blue!50!cyan}
  \fill [fill=\c, rotate=\i*45] (-22.5:0) -- (-22.5:5) arc (-22.5:22.5:5) -- cycle;
\foreach \r in {3,4,5}
  \fill [opacity=(\r^2)/35, even odd rule, fill=white] circle [radius=\r] circle [radius=\r-1];
\end{scope}

\foreach \emotionlist [count=\i] in
  {{terruer,peur,apprehension},
   {admiration,confiance,acceptation},
   {extase,joie,s\'er\'enit\'e},
   {vigilance,anticipation,in\'er\^et},
   {rage,col\`ere,agacement},
   {r\'epugnance,d\'ego\^ut,ennui},
   {chagrin,tristesse,rumination},
   {stup\'efaction,surprise,distraction}}
  \foreach \emotion [count=\j] in \emotionlist
    \node [anchor=base, font=\footnotesize, emotion label \i-\j/.try] at (\i*45-45:\j+.5) {\emotion};

\foreach \emotion [count=\i] in
{soumission, amour, optimisme, agressivit\`e,m\'epris,remords,d\`esapprobation,respect}
  \node [anchor=base, font=\footnotesize]
    at (\i*45-22.5:4.75) {\emotion};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MarkWibrow "I realise it is generally frowned upon to provide answers when the OP has not really done anything" ... and yet you do it. `:)`

Comment: Impressive how minimal your code is.

Comment: I am a beginner.For me it's too hard. Be humble !!!

Comment: Impressive ! Shame for me I am beginner !

Comment: @MarkWibrow  Very Elegant.  This would make a nice package, especially with the ability to select the number of pedals and the number of rings.  The is in the spirit of 'smartdiagram'.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a beginning - against my better judgement.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,x11names,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\newlength\myradius
\setlength\myradius{50mm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\large]
    \path [draw] circle (\myradius);
    \path [draw, densely dashed] circle (1.5\myradius) circle (2\myradius);
    \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l [count=\n]  in {ForestGreen/emotion/emotion/emotion,DeepSkyBlue2/emotion/emotion/emotion,blue/emotion/emotion/emotion,DarkViolet/emotion/emotion/emotion,red/emotion/emotion/emotion,orange/emotion/emotion/emotion,yellow/emotion/emotion/emotion,green/emotion/emotion/emotion}
    {
      \path [fill=\i, draw] (0,0) -- (67.5-45*\n:\myradius) coordinate (\n1) arc (67.5-45*\n:22.5-45*\n:\myradius) -- cycle;
      \path [fill=\i, fill opacity=.75, draw] (\n1) -- (57.5-45*\n:1.5\myradius) coordinate (\n3) arc (57.5-45*\n:32.5-45*\n:1.5\myradius) coordinate (\n4) -- (22.5-45*\n:\myradius) coordinate (\n2) arc (22.5-45*\n:67.5-45*\n:\myradius);
      \path [fill=\i, fill opacity=.5, draw] (\n3) -- (52.5-45*\n:2\myradius) coordinate (\n5) arc (52.5-45*\n:37.5-45*\n:2\myradius) coordinate (\n6) -- (\n4) arc (32.5-45*\n:57.5-45*\n:1.5\myradius);
      \path [fill=\i, fill opacity=.25, draw] (\n5) -- (45-45*\n:2.5\myradius) coordinate (\n7) -- (\n6) arc (37.5-45*\n:52.5-45*\n:2\myradius);
      \node at (45-45*\n:.75\myradius) {\j};
      \node at (45-45*\n:1.25\myradius) {\j};
      \node at (45-45*\n:1.75\myradius) {\j};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: emotions]

Comment: @HarishKumar Meaning I made it? Yes, but I don't approve! And I don't know how best to make the lines curve.